# Programming with speech recognition of microsoft. How could I close the speech recognition engine each time when it got a word

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am programming using the speech recognition of microsoft. I run an example and it works very well. But if I open the speech recognition, the program will be always inside. I want to each time the engine stops when it recognize the words. Is that possible.

My code is a little like this:

```
_trainer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
_trainer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(word))); // load a word
_trainer.SpeechRecognized += _trainer_SpeechRecognized;
_trainer.SpeechRecognitionRejected += _trainer_SpeechRecognitionRejected;
_trainer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // set the input to the default audio device
_trainer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Single);
```

Thanks for your help.

I tried to call `_trainer.Dispose()` at the end, but the engine will not work at all and gives me a break.

Comment: Is there something wrong with calling `Dispose`

Comment: I tried call the dispose() at the end. But if I call the dispose, it will stop in the middle. The engine could not work at all.

Comment: Wait until an appropriate time to call `Dispose`... What happens if you dispose of the class after [`RecognizeCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.recognizecompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @ta.speot.is I do not understand how to do it. Could you get me an example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add **RecognizeCompleted** event to **SpeechRecognitionEngine**

```
_trainer.RecognizeCompleted += _trainer_RecognizeCompleted;
```

inside the **_trainer_RecognizeCompleted** add

```
_trainer.RecognizeAsyncStop();
```

to cancel the  **SpeechRecognitionEngine** manually,

```
_trainer.RecognizeAsyncCancel();
```

to start **SpeechRecognitionEngine** again call **RecognizeAsync** again.

```
_trainer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Single);
```

See MSDN samples

1-)
[SpeechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync Method (RecognizeMode) (System.Speech.Recognition)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554584%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
2-)
[RecognizeMode Enumeration (System.Speech.Recognition)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognizemode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the engine is stop but the program is still on.

Comment: @cindywmiao i do not get the problem **program is still on?** Do you want to close the program after recognition complete?

Comment: I have an idea how to do that. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to stop the recognizer in the event speechRecognized (when a word is captured)

```
private void _trainer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Do your work 
         _trainer.RecognizeAsyncStop();
    }
```